# Is it better practice to use subquery in database?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Consider two tables with following schemas

```
Raipur_Restaurant_List

RestID
name
```

where RestID is the `primary key`

```
Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types

RestID
Dine_Name
```

where RestID is the `foreign key` referenced to Raipur_Restaurant_List table

```
select distinct RRL.RestID, RRL.name 
from Raipur_Restaurant_List as RRL 
join Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types as RRLDT 
on RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
where RRLDT.Dine_Name  = 'HomeDelivery' 
and RRL.RestID 
IN (select RestID from Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types where Dine_Name  ='Bakeries')
```

I am using above query to find those restaurants which have both HomeDelivery and Bakeries, Is there any better or efficient way to achieve this task ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this using just the one join and no subquery instead uses the `IN ()` to match *both* desired values, but also implements an aggregate `COUNT()` and limits the result set to those aggregate groups with `COUNT() = 2`, since that implies that it must have *both* values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  RRL.RestID,
  RRL.name
FROM
  Raipur_Restaurant_List as RRL 
  JOIN Raipur_Restaurant_List_Dine_Types as RRLDT 
    on RRL.RestID = RRLDT.RestID 
WHERE 
  -- Filter for both values
  RRLDT.Dine_Name IN ('HomeDelivery', 'Bakeries')
-- GROUP BY is needed to apply the COUNT()
GROUP BY
  RRL.RestID,
  RRL.name
-- And filter the aggregate groups 
-- for those having exactly two, meaning
-- both conditions were matched by the IN ()
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RRLDT.Dine_Name) = 2
```

The `IN()` clause itself would return rows having only one or the other of `HomeDelivery,Bakeries` in addition to both. By applying the `COUNT()`, you ensure that only those which match both are returned.

If you need to add additional matches, add them to the `IN ()` list, and also increment the number to compare in the `HAVING` clause to be the same as the length of the `IN ()` list.

The `DISTINCT` keyword inside `COUNT()` is only needed if it were possible for the *same* `Dine_Name` to exist more than once per `RestID`.  If there will never be duplicate `RestID, Dine_Name` pairs in `RRLDT`, the `DISTINCT` isn't needed there.

**[Here is a demonstration...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bbc5/1)**